# Next js random error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading'map')"

Tags: reactjs, next.js

So I am working with NextJs and facing random behavior. Once the application runs successfully, I do development and push code to Github. The next day I again run the app using `npm run dev` and face this.

[image]

So then I had to remove the repository and reset it again to make it work. But now today I am facing this again. I successfully worked yesterday, pushed the code to the git, and when I run this today I again face this error.
This seems to be something wrong with NextJS. Can anyone point out the cause?

Comment: Just delete the .next folder and try to run again. This happens to me all the time. And if that doesn't work try deleting the node_modules folder and running npm install again. That should solve your problem.

Comment: @Pranta oh so its not only me. and I think we do not have permanent solution for this

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else facing this annoying issue, @Pranta has already covered it. If it is random for you, and you aren't mapping anything, just do the following:

1. Delete the node_modules directory
2. Then `npm install` again.